# How to find this number, which is probably a very big prime or a product of big primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, computational-mathematics, experimental-mathematics, prime-gaps

Let $\mathcal{N}(n)$ be the next prime greater than $n$.

> Which is the smallest natural number $n>0\;$ such that:
>   $\mathcal N(2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot n)−2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot n\;\;\;$ is neither a prime nor $1$?

---

I'm sorry! I thought I had good reasons to believe that $n$ should be very big, but I should have tested it, because I was wrong about everything and $n=100284$. I might delete the question.

Comment: You mean $2\times 3\times 5\times 11\times \ldots \times n$ ?

Comment: @Luis Felipe VillavicencioLopez: NO!

Comment: Have you ruled out any values of $n$? It would be nice to say so if you have to keep others from double checking values that won't work. For instance, it doesn't work for $1\leq n\leq 5$.

Comment: Well it's at least 13, that's when I had to take a break because my dinner is ready

Comment: Ok, I think: $=2.3.5.7.11.n(\mathcal{N}-1)$, since $\mathcal{N}$ is prime, $\mathcal{N}-1=2k$ and o don't Know how to go on, i like the question, i'll work on it.

Comment: Ok it's at least 31. I'm starting to think this is a trick question.

Comment: @Luis Felipe VillavicencioLopez: $\mathcal N$ is s function not a number. But the question is rather a flop than a trick and I will delete it tomorrow.

Comment: $n$ is at least $52$.  This is a pretty interesting problem actually.

Comment: Don't delete it, this is a good problem.  The question is why does it take so long for $n$ to satisfy the condition?

Comment: Except for four cases, all such $n$ less than three million have a difference equal to $169 = 13^2$; the other four have a difference of $221 = 13\cdot 17$.

Comment: @rogerl, continuing we see 247 (13*19), 289 (17*17), 299 (13*23), 323 (17*19), 391 (17*23), 361 (19*19), 377 (13*29), 403 (13*31), 527 (17*31), 437 (19*23).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that the difference must be divisible by no prime less than $11$ (otherwise $\mathcal N(2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot n)$ would not be prime), so the smallest possible difference is $169$. The first occurrence of a prime gap of that magnitude is the pair $\{17051707, 17051887\}$. That doesn't fully explain why the smallest solution ($n=100284$ with product $231656040$) is as large as it is, but it comes close. Even though the prime gap is larger than $169$, you still need a product with high divisibility to fall in just the right place in that prime gap in order to get a solution.

Comment: This really explains why it takes so long before the difference become a composite. Even $\mathcal N(2n)-2n$ gives primes/1 for $n=1,\dots 58$.